# angular strap date picker not working in the visual force page.Need help on this issue

Tags: visualforce, angular

I am trying to use the angular strap(http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##datepickers) date picker component in the visual force page. I tried it as shown below,

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-autoclose="1" 
                  ng-model="selectedDate" name="date" data-bs-datepicker="1"></input> 
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.eponboarding_resources_common, 'app/lib/angular-strap.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.eponboarding_resources_common, 'app/lib/angular-sanitize.js')}"/>
<apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.eponboarding_resources_common, 'app/lib/angular-animate.js')}"/>
```

[image]

Need help to resolve the issue.

Comment: I configured like the below,

    <input type="text" class="form-control" data-autoclose="1" 
                      ng-model="selectedDate" name="date" data-bs-datepicker="1"></input>
    
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.eponboarding_resources_common, 'app/lib/angular-strap.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.eponboarding_resources_common, 'app/lib/angular-sanitize.js')}"/>
    <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.eponboarding_resources_common, 'app/lib/angular-animate.js')}"/>

Comment: You might get lucky and find someone who recognises something in what you have posted but I would be surprised... I observe that your link mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/##datepickers suggests that several other .js files are required and not least angular.js. The information you have posted does not make clear whether you have all of those. I suggest you get this working outside Salesforce first using a simple .html file and also make use of your browser's "Developer Tools" to get the basics working: learn how to use those tools. Later you can add Batarang to your browser too.